# What is the equivalent to PersistKeysToDbContext in ASP.NET 4.6?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to share my authentication Cookies between a ASP.NET Core application and a ASP.NET 4.X application.

I am following this tutorial: [Share authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1).  However I am stuck because our .NET Core application uses the `PersistKeysToDbContext` to share the Cookie keys:

```
 services.AddDataProtection()
       .SetApplicationName("MyApplicationName")
       .PersistKeysToDbContext<MyDatabaseContext>();
```

And, as per the tutorial, I will use the following code in my .NET 4.6 application:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "Identity.Application",
    CookieName = ".AspNet.SharedCookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity =
            SecurityStampValidator
                .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) =>
                        user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
        new DataProtectorShim(
            DataProtectionProvider.Create("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}",
                (builder) => { builder.SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp"); })
            .CreateProtector(
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies." +
                    "CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                "Identity.Application",
                "v2"))),
    CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
});
```

The `DataProtectionProvider.Create` does not seem to allow for either database storage or for custom storage.  I am completely stuck - how do I use SQL server to share the keys from .NET Core to .NET 4.6?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Flappy I posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did find the solution.  I implemented my own version of `PersistKeysToDbContext` .  Now the code for "TicketDataFormat" (in Startup.Auth.cs) looks like this:

```
    TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
                new DataProtectorShim(
                        DataProtectionProvider.Create(
                            new DirectoryInfo("{PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER}"),
                            (builder) => { 
                                builder.SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");
                                builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<KeyManagementOptions>>(services =>
                                {
                                    return new ConfigureOptions<KeyManagementOptions>(options =>
                                    {
                                        options.XmlRepository = new MyXmlRepository();
                                    });
                                });
                         }).CreateProtector(
                        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies." +
                            "CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                        "Cookies",
                        "v2"))),
```

You must now implement a class that reads and writes to the database, which must implement the interface `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.IXmlRepository` :

```
public class MyXmlRepository : IXmlRepository
{

    public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<XElement> GetAllElements()
    {
        // This function must return a list of all the elements in the database
    }

    public void StoreElement(XElement element, string friendlyName)
    {
        // This function must write to the database (this is optional if this
        // service never provides the authentication, only uses it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly taken from Microsoft's own extension methods; it's very similar to the accepted answer but doesn't require the DirectoryInfo to be specified:

```cs
TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
                    new DataProtectorShim(
                        CreateProvider(
                            builder =>
                            {
                                builder.SetApplicationName("YourSharedApplicationName");
                                builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<KeyManagementOptions>>(services =>
                                {
                                    return new ConfigureOptions<KeyManagementOptions>(options =>
                                    {
                                        options.XmlRepository = new DataProtectionXmlRepository();
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        )
                        .CreateProtector(
                            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                            // Must match the Scheme name used in the ASP.NET Core app, i.e. IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme
                            "Identity.Application",
                            "v2")))
```

The CreateProvider method:

```cs
        private static IDataProtectionProvider CreateProvider(Action<IDataProtectionBuilder> setupAction)
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            IDataProtectionBuilder dataProtectionBuilder = services.AddDataProtection();

            setupAction(dataProtectionBuilder);

            return ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>(services.BuildServiceProvider());
        }
```

...and finally your own implementation of IXmlRepository. This merely needs to retrieve a complete list of keys from the DB, and optionally write to it too, though that will only be needed if your legacy app is an authentication provider and not just a consumer.

```cs
        private class DataProtectionXmlRepository : IXmlRepository
        {
            public virtual IReadOnlyCollection<XElement> GetAllElements()
            {
                // Return a list of all the DataProtectionKeys in the database
                return SecurityManager.DataProtectionKeysGet();
            }

            public void StoreElement(XElement element, string friendlyName)
            {
                // Write to the database (not strictly needed as this service never provides the authentication, only uses it - but here for completeness)
                SecurityManager.DataProtectionKeyAdd(friendlyName, element.Value);
            }
        }
```